# Reading from serial port with while-loop

Tags: go

I’ve written a short program in Go to communicate with a sensor through a serial port:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tarm/goserial"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := &serial.Config{Name: "/dev/ttyUSB0", Baud: 9600}
    s, err := serial.OpenPort(c)

    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
    }

    _, err = s.Write([]byte("\x16\x02N0C0 G A\x03\x0d\x0a"))

    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second/2)

    buf := make([]byte, 40)
    n, err := s.Read(buf)

    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))

    s.Close()
}
```

It works fine, but after writing to the port I have to wait about half a second before I can start reading from it. I would like to use a while-loop instead of `time.Sleep` to read all incoming data. My attempt doesn’t work:

```
buf := make([]byte, 40)
n := 0

for {
    n, _ := s.Read(buf)

    if n > 0 {
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))
```

I guess `buf` gets overwritten after every loop pass. Any suggestions?

Comment: Package `github.com/tarm/goserial` was deprecated in February 2015. Package `github.com/tarm/serial`, by the same author, can be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is that `Read()` will return whenever it has some data - it won't wait for all the data.  See the [io.Reader specification](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) for more info

What you want to do is read until you reach some delimiter.  I don't know exactly what format you are trying to use, but it looks like maybe `\x0a` is the end delimiter.

In which case you would use a [bufio.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadBytes) like this

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(s)
reply, err := reader.ReadBytes('\x0a')
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(reply)
```

Which will read data until the first `\x0a`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So far, it works fine, but I still have to use `time.Sleep`, otherwise I will get a `panic: EOF`, because the buffer is empty at the time of reading. (By the way: the end delimiter is `\x03`. After it, a checksum of two hex bytes follows.)

Comment: Strange - I wouldn't have thought a serial device should ever give EOF, and it definitely shouldn't just because the buffer is empty. The only possibility I can think of is it is dropping DTR/DSR. Make sure you are using a cable with only pin 2 and pin 3 (Rx and Tx) connected, leave all the other handshake lines disconnected. You might have to loop back DTR to DSR on the device but you shouldn't have to on the PC.

Comment: You might want to check and see if the package you're using has a blocking Read call or maybe a blocking "WaitForData" call. There's a difference between "no data yet" and "there will never be any more data" (the latter is what EOF signifies), so I'm confused as to why they're giving you EOF - they shouldn't be doing that. In any case, a blocking call might do what you're looking for, if it's implemented.

Comment: I suppose, there is no blocking mode implemented in the library, as you can see in the source: https://github.com/tarm/goserial/blob/master/serial_posix.go Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above?

Comment: Nope, because I'm using an USB/RS-232-adapter, attached to a serial cable with 4-pin LEMO connector.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess buf gets overwritten after every loop pass. Any suggestions?

Yes, `buf` will get overwritten with every call to `Read()`.

A timeout on the file handle would be the approach I would take.

```
s, _ := os.OpenFile("/dev/ttyS0", syscall.O_RDWR|syscall.O_NOCTTY|syscall.O_NONBLOCK, 0666)

t := syscall.Termios{
    Iflag:  syscall.IGNPAR,
    Cflag:  syscall.CS8 | syscall.CREAD | syscall.CLOCAL | syscall.B115200,
    Cc:     [32]uint8{syscall.VMIN: 0, syscall.VTIME: uint8(20)}, //2.0s timeout
    Ispeed: syscall.B115200,
    Ospeed: syscall.B115200,
}

// syscall
syscall.Syscall6(syscall.SYS_IOCTL, uintptr(s.Fd()),
    uintptr(syscall.TCSETS), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&t)),
    0, 0, 0)

// Send message
n, _ := s.Write([]byte("Test message"))

// Receive reply
for {
    buf := make([]byte, 128)
    n, err = s.Read(buf)
    if err != nil { // err will equal io.EOF
        break
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", string(buf))
}
```

Also note, if there is no more data read and there is no error, os.File.Read() will return an error of `io.EOF`,
[as you can see here.](https://golang.org/src/os/file.go?s=3218:3266#L81)