# How to read data from serial and process it when a specific delimiter is found

Tags: go

I have a device, which continues to send data over a serial port.
Now I want to read this and process it.
The data send this delimiter `"!"` and
as soon as this delimiter appears I want to pause reading to processing the data thats already been received.
How can I do that? Is there any documentation or examples that I can read or follow.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please follow these guides https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to receive help

Answer (score 1):

For reading data from a serial port you can find a few packages on Github, e.g. [tarm/serial](https://github.com/tarm/serial).

You can use this package to read data from your serial port. In order to read until a specific delimiter is reached, you can use something like:

```
config := &serial.Config{Name: "/dev/ttyUSB", Baud: 9600}

s, err := serial.OpenPort(config)
if err != nil {
    // stops execution
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// golang reader interface
r := bufio.NewReader(s)

// reads until delimiter is reached
data, err := r.ReadBytes('\x21')
if err != nil {
    // stops execution
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// or use fmt.Printf() with the right verb
// https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing
fmt.Println(data)
```

See also: [Reading from serial port with while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599232/reading-from-serial-port-with-while-loop)

Answer (score 1):

`bufio`'s reader unfortunately did not work for me - it kept crashing after a while. This was a no-go since I needed a stable solution for a low-performance system.

My solution was to implement [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599232/reading-from-serial-port-with-while-loop) with a small tweak. As noted, if you don't use `bufio`, the buffer gets overwritten every time you call

```golang
n, err := s.Read(buf0)
```

To fix this, append the bytes from `buf0` to a second buffer, `buf1`:

```golang
if n > 0 {
    buf1 = append(buf1, buf0[:n]...)
}
```

Then parse the bytes stored in `buf1`. If you find a subset you're looking for, process it further.

- make sure to clear the buffers in a suitable manner
- make sure to limit the frequency the loop is running with (e.g. `time.Sleep`)